# What does LINQ's Select(a => a) do?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking at the following code

```
    public IEnumerable<RoleRecord> GetRoles() {
        var roles = _roleRepository.Table.Select(role => role);
        return roles.ToList();
    }
```

the `Table` is `IQueryable<RoleRecord> Table { get; }`

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Select(role => role)` effectively projects to itself - so basically does nothing here.

```
return  _roleRepository.Table.ToList();
```

...will achieve the same, or:

```
return _roleRepository.Table;
```

If you are happy returning the enumerable and not a resolved list.

This is making the guess that `Table` is a valid `IEnumerable<T>` to be eligible for `Select()` or `ToList()`.

The `ToList` would fully iterate the `Table` enumerable, but is returned as an `IEnumerable<T>`. Consumers of that are going to be iterating the list, which might be cheaper than iterating the `Table`.

**Update:** after chatting with @servy, one important difference between returning an `IEnumerable<T>` (in your case, from `Select(role => role)`) and returning a `List<T>` is that with a `List<T>`, the caller can cast your `IEnumerable<T>` back to a `List<T>` and mutate it:

```
IEnumerable<RoleRecord> results = GetRoles();
var asList = (List<RoleRecord>)results;
asList.Add(new RoleRecord());
asList.RemoveAt(0);
```

Do note, however, that the self-projection isn't the deciding factor here, it is the fact that you are using an iterator block as the `IEnumerable<T>` implementation and not a `List<T>`.

That said, this particular behavioural difference won't be apparent in your case because you call `ToList()`, so the code in the original answer stands - it is equivalent (and technically slightly faster).

Comment: Note that if you weren't going to just `ToList` the whole thing then the identity project *would* serve a purpose; it would prevent the caller from casting the `IEnumerable` to it's underlying type and performing some actions that you intended to hide.  `Select` will use an iterator block, thus creating an underlying type with no additional (useful) information.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I don't follow. Can you post an example?

Comment: Sure, [example](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-18-tolookup.aspx).  Look near the end, just after, `"There are only two points of interest, really:"`  It would be too much code to put into a comment directly.

Comment: @Servy Ah yes I see, you mean they can take the return and cast it back to a `List<T>`. In this instance it might still be of no use as opposed to just returning `.Table`, but that entirely depends on what type `.Table` actually is. I think it is important not to confuse the projection and the `Select`, the self projection doesn't offer that behaviour, it is simply used because there is no overload of `Select` that takes no arguments. Interesting either way, I'll amend my answer with a warning.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any need to call Select if it doesn't have any filter criteria.

Something like:

```
 public IEnumerable<RoleRecord> GetRoles() {
        return _roleRepository.Table.ToList();
    }
```

would be simpler? Calling .ToList() would obviously hydrate the collection but I assume this is what you wanted.

Comment: There are occasions in which an identity `Select` means something (to prevent the caller from casting the result to some underlying type and modifying it), although this isn't one of those times.  Here it is indeed pointless.

Answer (score 1):

That should simplify to:

```
  public IEnumerable<RoleRecord> GetRoles() {
        return _roleRepository.Table.ToList();
    }
```

Basically, `a => a` is just an "identity" projection, that is, `a` goes to itself.  It really doesn't buy anything in this case.

It is occasionally useful as a placeholder, in some cases, when you don't want an action done.  But, in this case, there is no need, because the end result is just to perform a `ToList()` on the original sequence, which can be done directly without the `Select()`.

This is assuming, of course, that there's nothing else going on between the two lines in the original method.

Answer (score 1):

What does LINQ's `Select(a => a)` do?

It projects each element of a sequence into a new form that contains only the elements you specified ( your 'a').

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just write:

```
public IEnumerable<RoleRecord> GetRoles() {
    return _roleRepository.Table.ToList();
}
```

If not, then you could try

```
return (from r in _roleRepository.Table select r).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second snippet?  It's adding in the pointless entity projection again.

Answer (score 1):

The Select method returns a "projection" - a modification of each individual element of the source enumerable. In this case it projects the element to itself, so it's redundant.

If I had to guess as to the intent, I would say that the select was included, and the query was not inlined with its "ToList()" terminator (forces evaluation of the Linq chain to produce all elements), so that it could be more easily debugged to see exactly what elements were being produced by the query. Or, this query may have originally been written by someone versed in SQL who thinks all LINQ queries should have the parts of a SQL SELECT query.

Anyway, in addition to removing the Select, this query can also be inlined in the return:

```
public IEnumerable<RoleRecord> GetRoles() {
    return _roleRepository.Table.ToList();
}
```